# Why does this function not need a require statement?

Tags: erc-20, library, require, openzeppelin-contracts

Why does the following function not need a require statment?

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    _allowed[from][msg.sender] = _allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
    _transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
```

This function is a part of the ERC20 standard from the [OpenZeppelin library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol).

I would have thought that this function would first need to check the allowance of the `msg.sender` via a `require` statement that resembles the following:

```
require(_allowed[from][msg.sender] <= value);
```

Why is this require statement unnecessary?

Comment: Presumably, the `sub()` function (from the SafeMath library, I would guess?) reverts if the subtraction underflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_allowed[from][msg.sender]` is an array which maintains the list of allowance provided to spender. Subtract function of `SafeMath` [library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol#L40) here  checks:

```
require(b <= a);
```

Which ensures that in this line

```
_allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
```

value is less than or equal to the provided allowance otherwise it will throw. In case of unallowed allowance, this `require` will only pass when `value` is `0` which doesn't affect anything except costing the gas to caller.